# check if the values in column B exist in column A Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have this dataframe below

```
   a_number       b_number
0   343              991
1   991              633
2   343              633
3   633              628
4   343              633
5   628              916
6   697              886
7   916              572
8   697              884
9   886              125
```

I am trying to determine whether there is an entry in a Pandas `column b_number` that has a particular value in `column a_number`. I tried to do this with `b_number in a_number`. But it's only returned True or False. Meanwhile the result that I want is the value in b_number that is in the column a:

```
991
633
628
916
886
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please Try `df[df.a_number.isin(df.b_number)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
In [3262]: df[df.a_number.isin(df.b_number)].a_number
Out[3262]: 
1    991
3    633
5    628
7    916
9    886
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sets:

```
set_a = set(df['a_number'].values.tolist())
set_b = set(df['b_number'].values.tolist())
set.intersection(set_a, set_b)
```

First cast each column into a set, then use the `set.intersection` method to find any common values between `a_number` and `b_number`.